# How can I allow concurrent writes on different parts (with different keys) of a guava multimap

Tags: java, synchronization, locking, guava

I'm using google guava multimap and would like to know if it's possible to allow concurrent writes to different parts of the map or do I have to synchronize all access? When I say different parts, I mean different key-value pairs in the multimap.

Is the following sample code correct?

```
  class Key {}
  class Value {}

  private Multimap<Key, Value> multimap = HashMultimap.create();

  private final Striped<Key> locks = Striped.readWriteLock(100);

  public void write(final Key key, final Collection<Value> values) {
     Lock writeLock = locks.get(key).writeLock();
     writeLock.lock();

     try {
        for (Value value : values) {
           multimap.put(key, value);
        }
     } finally {
       writeLock.unlock();
     }
  }

  public Collection<Value> read(final Key key) {
     Lock readLock = locks.get(key).readLock();
     readLock.lock();

     try {
      // Collect values
     } finally {
       readLock.unlock();
     }
  }
```

Comment: Guava doesn't currently have any support for multithreaded access to multimaps; you'll have to synchronize the whole shebang.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this you may be better off using a `ConcurrentHashMap<K, Set<V>>` and manually replicating the multimap semantics.

You might be able to create a `MultimapView` type that extends `Multimap` and provides a view into a `Map<K, Collection<V>>` - I'm not sure if there's a reason Guava doesn't provide that (it might not be efficient?). All I see in `Multimaps` is copy factories.